# GCP: requests to increase "CPUs (all regions)" quota keep getting rejected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, quota

I recently started using the Compute Engine Google Cloud Platform. Last week, I switched from the free trial to a paid plan. As my deployments were limited by the CPU quota, I requested increases for two quotas: "CPUs (europe-north1)" and "CPUs (all regions)". The europe-north1 quota was accepted right away and is now 512. However, my deployments are now still limited by the all regions quota, which is at 32.

I have not heard back about the all regions quota yet and any further requests get rejected right away with the following message:

```
We have received your quota request for [PROJECT].

Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this time. If this
is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the request or until your
Billing account has additional history.

Your Sales Rep is a good Escalation Path for these requests, and we highly
recommend you to reach out to them.

If you have any further questions, please reply to this thread or feel free to
reach out to us at gc-team@google.com.
```

I have no sales rep, so I contacted the gc-team@google.com address last week, but haven't heard from them since. I read that, apparently, this all regions quota [was introduced recently](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

What I have tried so far:

- Requested different numbers for the all regions quota.
- Made a manual payment, which went through.

However, my requests keep getting rejected and I am still limited to 32 CPU cores in total. Any ideas or hints on this?

---

*Update*: I have been using n1-standard-4 and n1-standard-8 instances. As soon as the total number of CPUs exceeds 32, GCP aborts deployment. For example, when I try to create 8 n1-standard-8 VMs, I receive the following error message (via terraform):

```
google_compute_instance.worker[3]: 1 error(s) occurred:
google_compute_instance.worker.3: Error waiting for instance to create: Quota 'CPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded.  Limit: 32.0 globally.
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error message that includes quota description. Also, please provide more details like: 1. type of VMs 2. number of VMs.

Comment: I added information on type and number of VMs and added the GCP error message.

Comment: Thanks! I provided some possible ways to solve your issue in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Will wait a couple of days if someone has some concrete experience with this problem and then accept

Comment: Sure, please update your question if you found any other options to solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue related only to your GCP quotas:

```
google_compute_instance.worker.3: Error waiting for instance to create: Quota 'CPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded.  Limit: 32.0 globally.
```

and unfortunately Server Fault community can do nothing with such issues.

Have a look at the email from Google Cloud Support again:

> Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this
>   time. If this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the
>   request or until your Billing account has additional history.
>
> Your Sales Rep is a good Escalation Path for these requests, and we
>   highly recommend you to reach out to them.
>
> If you have any further questions, please reply to this thread or feel
>   free to reach out to us at gc-team@google.com.

**To solve this issue** you can try steps below:

- Try to work for a while with current quotas, if it possible for your use case, to get some history on your account and after that [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).
- Try to split desired increase in quota into some steps that could be approved like 32 -> 64 -> 128 -> 256 -> 512.
- Try to reach [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).
- Try to reply again to `gc-team@google.com` but provide some arguments to clarify your request.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried again (after a couple of days) and GCP now allowed an increase to 256 CPUs. I will work with that for now and then request to increase further.

Comment: I am trying solution 1 to see it works. Solutions 2-4 not working.

Comment: @Shark Deng You are dealing with a credit situation. Is your credit good enough to justify a cloud vendor allowing access to resources that you pay for later? Review the credit card that you posted to your billing account. Does it only have $12.00 in credit available or are you using a corporate debit card? Are you a hobbyist or a business? How long has your account been open? These are factors that companies might consider in granting a credit line increase.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza don't know. I am looking at Microsoft Azure which claims to have 1 month free GPU. I got one best iMacPro which sadly doesn't have GPU and is too big to bring here.

Comment: Google's quota management in GCP definitely has some issues. I briefly tore down an instance but could not relaunch because my quota in the region got _reduced_ to 0! I have years of billing history. There's plenty of quota in other regions for the same project.Perhaps the real reason is that GCP does not have capacity in that region at this time.